# How create a yii2 multiple fields?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, field, yii2

Have a problem with yii2
How i can handle multiple fields?
My view must be like this link
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multiple-fields
Please can someone provide an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should using javascript to create fields and php form (not using yii).

Example:

The Html:

```
<div class="input">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <span class='add-input' href="#" name="name" onclick='addFields()'>Add</span>
</div>
```

The JS function:

```
function addFields(){
    var container_parent = document.getElementById('container');

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.name = "div_element";
    container_parent.appendChild(div);

    var new_field = document.createElement("input");
    new_field.name = 'new_name[]';
    div.appendChild(new_field);
}
```

Here I set name 'new_name[]' to when receive the post data, we using foreach ($_POST['new_name'] as value) to get all data.

If create select element:

```
function addFields(){
    var container_parent = document.getElementById('container');

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.name = "div_element";
    container_parent.appendChild(div);

    var new_field = document.createElement("select");
    new_field.name = 'new_name[]';
    div.appendChild(new_field);
    new_field.innerHTML = '<?php echo $option_items; ?>';
}
```

Here I add options value created by yii form:

```
$option_items =  $form->dropDownList($model, 'name', $allItems, array('prompt'=>'')); //get dropdownlist by yii
//remove data, just hold option value
$pos = strpos($option_items, "<option");
$rpos = strrpos($option_items, "</option>");
$option_items = substr($option_items, 0, $rpos+9);
$option_items = substr($option_items, $pos, strlen($option_items) - $pos);
$option_items = str_replace("\n", "", $option_items);
```

Or you can add your options value at:

```
new_field.innerHTML = '<?php echo $option_items; ?>';
```

You can modify to it cooler, good luck, sorry if my English is bad :)

Comment: so, the Algorithm i get values throw javascript then pass it to model (can i validate in model values&) and then post it to database?

Comment: Example your model is book, your attribute is category, in the controller, get $model = new Book; $model->category = $_POST... Using $model->vallidate to validate the attribute!

Comment: and how for example i can insert multiplie values to database?

Comment: Just set attribute to your model and save: $model->category = $_POST[...]; $model->id=...; $model->save(); (the 'category' is exist on database). If you have multiple value, just loop: foreach ($_POST['new_name'] as $value) {$model->id = ...;...; $model->category = $value; ...$model->save()  }

Comment: in yii2 i use activeform, in your example i donot need to use it?

Comment: My example using yii1, you can seach API for yii2.